# bash: cat the first lines of a file & get position

Tags: bash, file, cat

I got a very big file that contains n lines of text (with n being <1000) at the beginning, an empty line and then lots of untyped binary data.

I would like to extract the first n lines of text, and then somehow extract the exact offset of the binary data.

Extracting the first lines is simple, but how can I get the offset? bash is not encoding aware, so just counting up the number of characters is senseless.

Comment: What do you mean by offset? Do you have to extract a range of lines? Say for example from line 10 to line 20?

Comment: the offset in bytes. That is, the binary data starts at byte x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep has an option `-b` to output the byte offset.

Example:

```
$ hexdump -C foo 
00000000  66 6f 6f 0a 0a 62 61 72  0a                       |foo..bar.|
00000009
$ grep -b "^$" foo 
4:
$ hexdump -s 5 -C foo
00000005  62 61 72 0a                                       |bar.|
00000009
```

In the last step I used 5 instead of 4 to skip the newline.

Also works with umlauts (äöü) in the file.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `grep` to find the empty line**

```
grep -n "^$" your_file | tr -d ':'
```

Optionally use `tail -n 1` if you want the last empty line (that is, if the top part of the file can contain empty lines before the binary stuff starts).

**Use `head` to get the top part of the file.**

```
head -n $num
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use tools like [hexdump](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hexdump%201) or [od](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od) to retrieve binary offsets instead of bash. Here's a [reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/058).

Answer (score 1):

Perl can tell you where you are in a file:

```
pos=$( perl -le '
    open $fh, "<", $ARGV[0]; 
    $/ = "";  # read the file in "paragraphs" 
    $first_paragraph = <$fh>; 
    print tell($fh)
' filename )
```

Parenthetically, I was attempting to one-liner this

```
pos=$( perl -00 -lne 'if ($. == 2) {print tell(___what?___); exit}' filename
```

What is the "current filehandle" variable? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Don’t tell anything.  Just call `tell()` by itself there. If you do not pass an argument to tell, it tells you the seek pointer for the last file read from using the readline operator, `<>`.  Here it is implicit.